# Subsequences with distinct values

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence, integer-sequence

(this question was modified after initial answers)

For a sequence

```
x = {6,4,2,4,2,4,6}
```

```
y = Subsequences[x]
```

gives the list of all subsequences, I would like to find the subset m of these subsequences which have distinct values, where each subsequence is composed of consecutive values in x.  Or at most z repeat values.

subset m of subsequences of x with distinct values:

```
6
6,4
6,4,2
4
4,2
2
2,4
2,4,6
4,6
```

How can I remove the subsequences with duplicate values?

Is it possible to give the starting list position in x for each of the m?

Comment: try `z = 1; Select[EqualTo[z]@*Max@*Counts]@y`?

Comment: Should `4,6` be part of your subsequence? If so then just add `DeleteDuplicates` to @kglr 's code ie `DeleteDuplicates@*Select[EqualTo[z]@*Max@*Counts]@y`

Comment: Yes thanks I added 4,6

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this without using Subsequence[]?
For larger sequences, my PC can't calculate this

Comment: if `z=2` is this the desired output ? `{{6}, {6, 4}, {6, 4, 2}, {6, 4, 2, 4}, {6, 4, 2, 4, 2}, {4}, {4, 
  2}, {4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 2}, {2}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 2, 
  4}, {2, 4, 2, 4, 6}, {4, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {4, 6}}`

Comment: Yes, that would give z=2 duplicate values for each distinct value maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an iterative approach:

```
(*input*)
x = {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6};
z = 2;

$sizeOfSetX = Length[x];
$subsetM = {};

Do[
  maximumSubsequenceLength = $sizeOfSetX - startOfSubsequence + 1;

  Do[
    endOfSubsequence = startOfSubsequence + lengthOfSubsequence - 1;
    candidateSubsequence = x[[startOfSubsequence ;; endOfSubsequence]];

    (* check constraint of max repeated values*)
    If[ Count[candidateSubsequence, x[[endOfSubsequence]]] > z , Break[] ];

    (* check constraint of uniqueness*)
    If[ Not@MemberQ[$subsetM, candidateSubsequence] , AppendTo[$subsetM, candidateSubsequence] ]
    ,
    {lengthOfSubsequence, maximumSubsequenceLength}
  ]

  ,
  {startOfSubsequence, $sizeOfSetX}
];

$subsetM (*{{6}, {6, 4}, {6, 4, 2}, {6, 4, 2, 4}, {6, 4, 2, 4, 2}, {4}, {4, 
  2}, {4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 2}, {2}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 2, 
  4}, {2, 4, 2, 4, 6}, {4, 2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}, {4, 6}}*)
```

Comment: I was hoping I could `Compile` this but am struggling. I suspect it is because `$subsetM` is a list of lists of differing lengths. Would be very appreciative if anyone could post a compiled answer.

Comment: I think there are sequences missing, namely: {4, 2, 4, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6}, {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4}, {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6}

Comment: @DanielHuber, the missing sequences you highlight violate the constraint of z=2, ie at most 2 repeated values

Answer (score 4):

```
x = {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6}
```

`uniqueElemsQ` is a helper function that returns `True` if all list elements are distinct.

```
uniqueElemsQ[k_List] := Not@(Union[(Last /@ Tally[k])] != {1})
```

The  `ReplaceList` command generates all consecutive non-empty sublists.

```
Select[ReplaceList[x, {___, a__, ___} :> {a}], 
  uniqueElemsQ] // DeleteDuplicates
```

> {{6}, {6, 4}, {6, 4, 2}, {4}, {4, 2}, {2}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 6}, {4, 6}}

Comment: Does this only work for the case `z=1` ?

Comment: Yes, when there are no duplicates in the list.

Comment: Hi Syed, I think your uniqueElemsQ is the same as [DuplicateFreeQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html).

Comment: I was on my to making something more based on `Tally` but then I realized that the problem was more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6};
subs = Subsequences[Union[x]]

{{}, {2}, {4}, {6}, {2, 4}, {4, 6}, {2, 4, 6}}
```

You can remove the empty set by selecting the nonempty elements

```
Select[subs, # != {} &]
```

Comment: That isn't quite what I was trying to find, I'd like to find subsequences that exist as consecutive values in x.  I edited the question to indicate this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Subsequences[x]//Select[DuplicateFreeQ]//Union
```

Also, SequencePosition will give you the location of a subsequence.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution:

```
subseqs[x_,z_]:=Flatten[Rest[FoldWhileList[Select[
  DeleteDuplicates[Subsequences[x,{#2}]],
    (Max[Values[Counts[#]]]<=z)&]&,0,Range[Length[x]],(#=!={})&]],1];
```

Example:

```
subseqs[{6,4,2,4,2,4,6},2]
(* {{6},{4},{2},
    {6,4},{4,2},{2,4},{4,6},
    {6,4,2},{4,2,4},{2,4,2},{2,4,6},
    {6,4,2,4},{4,2,4,2},{2,4,2,4},{4,2,4,6},
    {6,4,2,4,2},{2,4,2,4,6}} *)
```

**Note.** The goal was to be somewhat efficient in the case when `x` is a long list, but contains only a small number of distinct elements. This situation was mentioned by OP in a previous version of the question. An artificial example is:

```
SeedRandom[1];
x=RandomChoice[Range[6],1000000];

AbsoluteTiming[Length[subseqs[x,1]]]
{9.8393, 1956}

AbsoluteTiming[Length[subseqs[x,2]]]
{52.5905, 622610}
```

For comparison, the current version of the [currently accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274394/85954) takes 45 seconds in the first case on my machine, and $>360$ seconds in the second case.

Comment: (+1) For your solution.

Comment: Nice answer and some things to learn for me: I have not seen `FoldWhileList` or `=!=` before.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6};

y = Subsequences @ x;
```

Positions of subsets with distinct values

```
p = Position[Values @* Counts /@ y, {1..}]
```

> {{2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13},
> {14}, {15}, {19}}

Using `Extract`

```
NumericalSort @ Union @ Extract[y, p]
```

> {{2}, {4}, {6}, {2, 4}, {4, 2}, {4, 6}, {6, 4}, {2, 4, 6}, {6, 4, 2}}